# PIVOT two columns and keep others as they are

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I want to turn some of the rows into columns while keeping other rows as they are.

```
ID      name     value     RefId
1       Fname    John      32145
2       LName    Smith     32145
3       Fname    Peter     34589
4       LName    Mahlang   34589
```

Now what I want to achieve is to turn the `Fname` and `Lname` rows into columns with their matching `value` field. `ID` column doesn't really matter, I don't need it.

**Desired Output**

```
       Fname     Lname     RefId
       John      Smith     32145
       Peter     Mahlang   34589
```

Any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    Fname = max(case when name = 'Fname' then value end)
  , Lname = max(case when name = 'Lname' then value end)
  , RefId
from t
group by RefId
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/MRMY11592

returns:

```
+---------+---------+-------+
|  Fname  |  Lname  | RefId |
+---------+---------+-------+
| John    | Smith   | 32145 |
| Peter   | Mahlang | 34589 |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

---

Or using `pivot()`

```
select 
    Fname
  , Lname
  , RefId
from (select name, value, refid from t) s
pivot(max(value) for name in ([Fname],[Lname]))p
```

Comment: Thanks SqlZim. It works perfectly. Much appreciate your help.