# How to get max and min of columns per row for pivoted table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Big thanks to [@JohnCappelletti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1570000/john-cappelletti) as he's shown how to pivot a table.

This is a sample data:

```
DECLARE @OperatorPrice TABLE (ID int NOT NULL, OperatorId INT NULL, Price 
    NUMERIC(18,3) NULL, FName VARCHAR(50) NULL)

INSERT INTO @OperatorPrice (
    ID, OperatorId, Price, FName
)
VALUES
(226, 996, 22954,'Operator1')
, (266, 1016, 79011.2,   'Operator3')
, (112, 1029, 14869,     'Operator4')
, (112, 996, 22954,      'Operator1')
, (93,   1031, 10568.96, 'Operator5')


DECLARE @TR TABLE 
(
      ID varchar(25) NULL  
    , MinPrice DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, MaxPrice DECIMAL(18,3) NULL
    , SumCount DECIMAL(18,3) NULL 
    , Operator1  DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, OC1  DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, Operator2  
        DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, 
    OC2  DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, Operator3  DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, OC3  
    DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, 
    Operator4  DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, OC4  DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, Operator5  
    DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, 
    OC5  DECIMAL(18,3) NULL
)
```

The pivot code:

```
INSERT @TR
SELECT *
FROM  (
    Select B.*
    From  @OperatorPrice A
    Cross Apply ( values  (0,FName,Price)
                     , (0,'OC'+replace(FName,'Operator',''),OperatorID)
                     , (A.ID,'MinPrice', A.Price)
                     , (A.ID,'MaxPrice', A.Price)
                     , (A.ID,'SumCount', A.OperatorId)
                     , (A.ID,FName,Price)
                     , (A.ID,'OC'+replace(FName,'Operator',''),OperatorID)
             ) B (ID,Item,Value)
     Union All
     Select
         ID=0
         , B.*
     From ( Select Top 50 N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
         From master..spt_values n1 ) A
     Cross Apply ( values (concat('Operator',N),NULL)
                     ,(concat('OC',N),NULL)
             ) B (Item,Value)
  ) AS SourceTable        
  PIVOT  ( sum(Value) FOR Item IN (MinPrice, MaxPrice, SumCount,Operator1, 
      OC1, Operator2, OC2,  
      Operator3, OC3, Operator4, OC4,  Operator5, OC5) ) AS PivotTable

  SELECT * FROM @TR
```

The above code works perfectly, except `MinPrice` and `MaxPrice` are wrong! Currently they are `Sum()` of `Price`:

[image]

But I need `Min()` of price and `Max()` of `Price` column. **So the desired output should looks like this:**

[image]

How to get `Min()` of price and `Max()` of `Price` column for the row of pivoted table?

Comment: I think you should read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Important key word : `minimal`

Comment: @MatBailie I've pasted a code for reproduce the problem and input data. What should I do to improve my question?

Comment: Just use conditional aggregation.  `PIVOT` isn't flexible.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It would be really cool, if you show it. I do not know how to do it. I do not have idea how to do it.

Comment: Lookup pivot on multiple columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gordon is correct, since you are mixing aggregations, the conditional aggregation may be more performant.

However, by adding a couple of `UNION ALLs` we can get the desired results

**Example**

```
DECLARE @OperatorPrice TABLE (ID int NOT NULL, OperatorId INT NULL, Price 
    NUMERIC(18,3) NULL, FName VARCHAR(50) NULL)

INSERT INTO @OperatorPrice (
    ID, OperatorId, Price, FName
)
VALUES
(226, 996, 22954,'Operator1')
, (266, 1016, 79011.2,   'Operator3')
, (112, 1029, 14869,     'Operator4')
, (112, 996, 22954,      'Operator1')
, (93,   1031, 10568.96, 'Operator5')


DECLARE @TR TABLE 
(
      ID varchar(25) NULL  
    , MinPrice DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, MaxPrice DECIMAL(18,3) NULL
    , SumCount DECIMAL(18,3) NULL 
    , Operator1  DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, OC1  DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, Operator2  
        DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, 
    OC2  DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, Operator3  DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, OC3  
    DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, 
    Operator4  DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, OC4  DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, Operator5  
    DECIMAL(18,3) NULL, 
    OC5  DECIMAL(18,3) NULL
)



INSERT @TR
SELECT *
FROM  (
    Select B.*
    From  @OperatorPrice A
    Cross Apply ( values  (0,FName,Price)
                        , (0,'OC'+replace(FName,'Operator',''),OperatorID)
                        , (A.ID,'SumCount', A.OperatorId)
                        , (A.ID,FName,Price)
                        , (A.ID,'OC'+replace(FName,'Operator',''),OperatorID)
             ) B (ID,Item,Value)
     Union All 
     Select ID,Item='MinPrice',Value=min(Price) From @OperatorPrice Group By ID
     Union All
     Select ID,Item='MaxPrice',Value=max(Price) From @OperatorPrice Group By ID
     Union All
     Select 0,Item='MinPrice',Value=min(Price) From @OperatorPrice 
     Union All
     Select 0,Item='MaxPrice',Value=max(Price) From @OperatorPrice
     Union All
     Select 0,Item='SumCount',Value=sum(OperatorId) From @OperatorPrice
     Union All
     Select
         ID=0
         , B.*
     From ( Select Top 50 N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
         From master..spt_values n1 ) A
     Cross Apply ( values (concat('Operator',N),NULL)
                     ,(concat('OC',N),NULL)
             ) B (Item,Value)
  ) AS SourceTable        
  PIVOT  ( sum(Value) FOR Item IN (MinPrice, MaxPrice, SumCount,Operator1, 
      OC1, Operator2, OC2,  
      Operator3, OC3, Operator4, OC4,  Operator5, OC5) ) AS PivotTable

  SELECT * FROM @TR
```

**Returns**

[image]

Note: I added the Total Min, Max, SumCount for ID 0

Comment: Thanks a lot! John, you are really cool!  Thank you very much!

Comment: @StepUp There was a day when I was cool ... it was a Thursday.  Thanks for the grin  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your entire code with the following:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MinPrice IS NOT NULL THEN Mn END MinPrice,
       CASE WHEN MaxPrice IS NOT NULL THEN Mx END MaxPrice,
SumCount , Operator1 , OC1 , Operator2 , OC2 , Operator3 , OC3 ,Operator4 , OC4 ,Operator5 , OC5
 FROM 
 (--This is where your part starts
    SELECT *
    FROM  (
        Select B.*
        From  @OperatorPrice A
        Cross Apply ( values  (0,FName,Price)
                         , (0,'OC'+replace(FName,'Operator',''),OperatorID)
                         , (A.ID,'MinPrice', A.Price)
                         , (A.ID,'MaxPrice', A.Price)
                         , (A.ID,'SumCount', A.OperatorId)
                         , (A.ID,FName,Price)
                         , (A.ID,'OC'+replace(FName,'Operator',''),OperatorID)
                 ) B (ID,Item,Value)
         Union All
         Select
             ID=0
             , B.*
         From ( Select Top 50 N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
             From master..spt_values n1 ) A
         Cross Apply ( values (concat('Operator',N),NULL)
                         ,(concat('OC',N),NULL)
                 ) B (Item,Value)
      ) AS SourceTable        
      PIVOT  ( sum(Value) FOR Item IN (MinPrice, MaxPrice, SumCount,Operator1, 
          OC1, Operator2, OC2,  
          Operator3, OC3, Operator4, OC4,  Operator5, OC5) ) AS PivotTable --This is where your part ends
    ) main
CROSS APPLY 
(
SELECT  MIN(X.t) Mn , MAX(X.t) Mx 
FROM 
    (
    VALUES (Operator1) , (Operator2) , (Operator3) , (Operator4) , (Operator5)
    ) x (t)
) Q
```