# Create dynamic PIVOT table with several aggregated functions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I am trying to create a pivot table. The source one is following:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+--------+--------+------------+
| UserId | LastName   | FirstName | Param1 | Param2 | Date       |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------+--------+------------+
| 1      | Snow       | John      | Text1  | Text1  | 01-01-2019 |
| 2      | Lannister  | Tyrion    | Text1  | Text1  | 01-01-2019 |
| 3      | Targaryen  | Daenerys  | Text2  | Text2  | 01-01-2019 |
| 1      | Snow       | John      | Text3  | Text2  | 01-02-2019 |
| 2      | Lannister  | Tyrion    | Text3  | Text2  | 01-02-2019 |
| 3      | Targaryen  | Daenerys  | Text3  | Text3  | 01-02-2019 |
|        |            |           |        |        | … 120 days |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------+--------+------------+
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---+
| UserId | LastName   | FirstName | Param1:01-01-2019 | Param2:01-01-2019 | Param1:01-02-2019 | Param2:01-02-2019 | … |
+--------+------------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---+
| 1      | Snow       | John      | Text1             | Text1             | Text3             | Text2             | … |
| 2      | Lannister  | Tyrion    | Text1             | Text1             | Text3             | Text2             | … |
| 3      | Targaryen  | Daenerys  | Text2             | Text2             | Text3             | Text3             | … |
+--------+------------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---+
```

So, basically, I am trying to solve 2 questions:

1. Dynamically create 120 columns for dates.
2. Use 3 aggregate functions for Date, Param1 and Param2

**Note:** `Param1` and `Param2` columns have predefined values (around 10 each)

My starting static pivot query is like this:

```
WITH PivotData AS
(
      SELECT 
           [UserId]
          ,[Last Name]
          ,[First Name]
          ,[Param1]
          ,[Param2]
          ,[Date]
      FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
)
SELECT [Last Name], [First Name], [Param1:01-01-2019], [Param2:01-01-2019], [Param1:01-02-2019], [Param2:01-02-2019]
FROM PivotData
       PIVOT ( MAX([Param1]) FOR [Date] in ([Param1:01-01-2019], [Param1:01-01-2019]) ) AS P1
       PIVOT ( MAX([Param2) FOR [Date] in ([Param2:01-02-2019], [Param2:01-02-2019]) ) AS P2
```

**Update 1:**

I have used another query, but still need to do it dynamically, so original question remains

```
SELECT
[UserId]

MAX(CASE WHEN [Date] = '2019-01-01' THEN ISNULL([Param1], NULL) ELSE NULL END) AS [Param1:2019-01-01],
MAX(CASE WHEN [Date] = '2019-01-01' THEN ISNULL([Param2], NULL) ELSE NULL END) AS [Param2:2019-01-01],
MAX(CASE WHEN [Date] = '2019-01-01' THEN ISNULL([Param3], NULL) ELSE NULL END) AS [Param3:2019-01-01],

MAX(CASE WHEN [Date] = '2019-01-02' THEN ISNULL([Param1], NULL) ELSE NULL END) AS [Param1:2019-01-02],
MAX(CASE WHEN [Date] = '2019-01-02' THEN ISNULL([Param2], NULL) ELSE NULL END) AS [Param2:2019-01-02],
MAX(CASE WHEN [Date] = '2019-01-02' THEN ISNULL([Param3], NULL) ELSE NULL END) AS [Param3:2019-01-02],

FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
GROUP BY [UserId]
ORDER BY [UserId]
```

But logic is still confusing for me.
Please help.

Comment: maybe it can help to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52461516/calc-sum-total-of-pivoted-table-by-two-columns-into-predefined-table

Comment: use `Dynamic SQL` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This is simple, but you first you mentioned 2 columns and then 3. Which is the correct? It might not make a difference, but I just want it to be clear.

Comment: Also, is it 120 columns or 120 dates (times the number of columns)? Do you have a start date and end date or does it come from the table values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will create a list of 120 dates to then generate the group of columns requested.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

WITH 
E(n) AS( --11 rows
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( --11x11= 121 rows
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
cteTally(calDate) AS(
    SELECT TOP( 120)
        DATEADD( dd, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1, '20190101') calDate
    FROM E2
)
SELECT @SQL = 
    --Identify first static part of query. Columns that won't be pivoted.
    N'SELECT [UserId]'
    --Identify the dynamic part and set the pattern. Use FOR XML PATH to concatenate the values.
    + ( SELECT N'
            ,MAX(CASE WHEN [Date] = ''' + CONVERT( NCHAR(8), calDate, 112) + ''' THEN ISNULL([Param1], NULL) ELSE NULL END) AS [Param1:' + CONVERT( NCHAR(10), calDate, 120) + ']
            ,MAX(CASE WHEN [Date] = ''' + CONVERT( NCHAR(8), calDate, 112) + ''' THEN ISNULL([Param2], NULL) ELSE NULL END) AS [Param2:' + CONVERT( NCHAR(10), calDate, 120) + ']
            ,MAX(CASE WHEN [Date] = ''' + CONVERT( NCHAR(8), calDate, 112) + ''' THEN ISNULL([Param3], NULL) ELSE NULL END) AS [Param3:' + CONVERT( NCHAR(10), calDate, 120) + ']'
        FROM cteTally
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
    --Identify second static part of query. Everything starting with the FROM clause.
    + N'FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
GROUP BY [UserId]
ORDER BY [UserId];
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);'

--Used for debugging purposes
PRINT @SQL

--Execute the dynamic query. Use parameters when needed.
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL --, @ParamDefinition, @Param1, @Param2, ..., @ParamN;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you and for the comments also, now it is clear how this should be done :)

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comments, you need to use dynamic SQL. Based on your (small) sample this works, however, it's up to you if you need to make any changes to it to fit your needs. the `PRINT` statement is your friend (which you may well have to change to `SELECT` if you have over 4,000 characters):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SampleTable (UserId int,
                              LastName varchar(50),
                              FirstName varchar(50),
                              Param1 varchar(6),
                              Param2 varchar(6),
                              [Date] date);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.SampleTable
VALUES (1,'Snow','John','Text1','Text1','20190101'),
       (2,'Lannister','Tyrion','Text1','Text1','20190101'),
       (3,'Targaryen','Daenerys','Text2','Text2','20190101'),
       (1,'Snow','John','Text3','Text2','20190102'),
       (2,'Lannister','Tyrion','Text3','Text2','20190102'),
       (3,'Targaryen','Daenerys','Text3','Text3','20190102');
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT UserId,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                         N'       MAX(CASE [Date] WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(8),ST.[Date],112),'''') + N' THEN ' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + N' END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME + N':' + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10),ST.[Date],102),N'.',N'-'))
                  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                       CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [Date]
                                   FROM dbo.SampleTable) ST
                  WHERE C.TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo'
                    AND C.TABLE_NAME = N'SampleTable'
                    AND C.COLUMN_NAME LIKE N'Param%'
                  ORDER BY ST.[Date],
                           C.ORDINAL_POSITION                           
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,3,N'') + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
          N'FROM dbo.SampleTable' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
          N'GROUP BY UserId' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
          N'ORDER BY UserId;';
PRINT @SQL; --Your Debugging best friend
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

GO
DROP TABLE SampleTable
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2c5a451c96fc7c008faf2d515c1ddd7d)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, and for the comments also. I now understand how dynamic SQL works. I cannot mark 2 posts as answer, but I very appreciate your effort.